# PDO App - Login Not Functioning Properly

Tags: php, session, pdo

Alright, so I'm building a new app, and have decided to use PDO for database access. (I'm completely new to PDO, but am under the impression that it is the best way to go about db access).

Right now, my login script is incredibly simple. It checks the database for a user with the given username (from the login form), attempts to match the given password with the stored one in plain text (no encrypting/decrypting *yet*), and redirect the user as necessary. Here is a simple sequence diagram:

`Login Screen ---(user enters credentials)--->Login Handler---(gets user details and compares pw)-->if (pw == stored pw)--->dashboard / else --->login w/ error msg`

Sorry if that's hard to read, I wasn't sure the best way to represent the flow...anyways...

Here's my issue: I input the correct username and password (case sensitive even!), and am always redirected back to the login screen with the error message. However, if I simply go to the dashboard via the url bar, I am *not* redirected back to the login screen (as I should be if no session is set), and my username is displayed in the navigation bar (as if I had logged in correctly).

Again, sorry if this is hard to follow. Its sort of difficult to simply explain. If this is an issue, I can perhaps do a screencast of sorts to explain better. Either way, here is my code:

**loginHandler.php**

```
if(!isset($_POST['username']) || !isset($_POST['password'])){
    header('Location: login.php?error=pass');
}
$username = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

//TODO: crypt password

try{
    $DB = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=8889;dbname=cTix", 'root', 'root'); //TODO: change this when uploading to webserver
    $STH = $DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $username LIMIT 0, 1");
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $STH->execute();
    $u = $STH->fetch();
    if($pass == $u->password){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $u->id; //TODO: securely store uid
        header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
        //echo 'Your Password: ' . $pass . ' - Correct Password: ' . $u->password;
        header('Location: login.php?error=pass');
    }
} catch(PDOException $e){
    //echo $e->getMessage();
    header('Location: login.php?error=true');
    exit;
}
```

here is code that is retrieving the username for dashboard.php:

```
function connection(){
    $host = 'localhost';
    $dbname = 'cTix';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = 'root';
    try {
        $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
        return $DBH;
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}

function getUserById($id){
    $DB = connection();
    $STH = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id");
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $u = $STH->fetch();
    $DB = null;
    return $u;
}

function getUserName(){
    echo getUserById(getCurrentUserId())->name;
}
```

If there is any other information I can offer, or anything I can provide that would be more helpful, please let me know!

Unfortunately, without this stupid login issue figured out, I can't make any headway on this app, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks SO!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id` - if you're using PDO, you should really be using bound parameters, too.

Comment: you still are vulnerable for sql injection!

Comment: sorry...I'm going to remove the security tag from this question. The question is **NOT** about strongly securing the login. As it is now, I just want the basic functionality to **work**

Comment: I assume it's the comparison `$pass == $u->password` that's failing? If so, can you echo out the values for `$pass` and `$u->password`?

Comment: yeah...the code is actually in there to do that, but its commented out at the moment. Look at the `else` towards the end of the `try` block in **loginhandler.php**. When run, the password it pulls from the server is blank. So the validation is failing there, but idk why dashboard.php would still work? Sorry, its been awhile since I looked at this, but I've done a bit of debugging myself.

Comment: @JordanForeman - what does it print out when you uncomment it? Is it printing what you expect it to be printing?

Comment: `Your Password: abc123 - Correct Password:` -- so the password that is supposed to be pulled from the server is blank...this is not the intention of the code. I'm assuming the way my PDO interaction code is written is wrong, but as I'm completely new to PDO, idk what the problem could is.

Comment: @JordanForeman - I've added an answer for you. And some more nagging about bound parameters, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's where your problem is:

```
$STH = $DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $username LIMIT 0, 1");
```

You're concatenating the username into your SQL string, but not quoting it out. I suspect that this will fix the problem:

```
$STH = $DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 0, 1");
```

**HOWEVER**

You should look into how to use bound parameters. You're already using PDO, but you're still writing user-entered code in your SQL, and bound parameters avoid that - it would also have avoided this problem, too.

This ought to work, but I've not tested it:

```
$STH = $DB->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 0, 1');
$STH->bindParam(1, $username);
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$STH->execute();
```

Comment: thanks! It looks like the quotes are solving the query issue. My code still needs a bit of work, but I believe that it is out of the scope of this question (now I'm being redirected back to the login screen with no errors, so there's an issue in my maze of redirects). As far as bound variables go, as a student, I'm still learning. I guess you don't know what you don't know, so thank you very much for the tip, and I'm looking into it now!

Comment: @JordanForeman - you're welcome. It's something that's worth learning about at the start so you don't have to worry about it in the future.